¿cómo trabajar con ajax para actualizar una tabla que está dentro de un modal?
Saludos estoy abriendo un modal donde se carga los registros de la tabla a partir de un id que se genera cuando abro el modal, después de generar el id se inserta en la BDatos, cuando abro el modal en intento guardar en la tabla no lo muestra puesto que la tabla aparece en blanco pero si se inserta en la base de datos, genero el id de la consulta de forma incremental no se si la tabla cuando actualiza el ajax tomo el siguiente número incremental y por eso no lo muestra:
muestro el código donde creo el id:
                 $tabla = "salidas";
                 $id_ordenreg = 1;
                 $id_orden = ModeloOperaciones::mdlMostrarTabla($tabla, null, null);
                 //   print_r( $id_orden);
                 if (empty($id_orden)) {
                   $id_ordenreg = 1;
                 //  $id_orden = ModeloOperaciones::mdlIngresarSalida($tabla, $id_ordenreg);
                 } else {
                     
                   foreach ($id_orden as &$valor) {
                     $id_ordenreg++;
                   }
                 }
                 $valor = $id_ordenreg;
                 ?>

utilizo esta instrucción para actualizar mi tabla .load():
  $('#Tabsalidas').load('index.php?ruta=salidas #tabsalidas')
cambe mencionar que si vuelvo insertar registro en la tabla me lo guarda en el siguiente id
